# re.split(r'\W+', 'Words, words, words.') output ['Words', 'words', 'words', '']

Tags: python, regex

I read the example in Python official docs reference to regex 
[re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.split)

```
>>> re.split(r'\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', 'words', 'words', '']
```

I am confused with the output, I guess it will produce

```
[",",  ",",  ","]
```

I think the following is legible:

```
In [100]: re.split(r',', 'Words, words, words.')
Out[100]: ['Words', ' words', ' words.']
```

How could `(r'\W+', 'Words, words, words.'` output that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\W` character stands for anything which is **not** a word (`\w`), that is,  anything which is not a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

In your case, the `,` matches the `\W+` expression (one or more characters which is not an alphanumeric character or an underscore), which is why you are ending up with an alphabetic output.